# Certificate Pinning issue(ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then'))

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, certificate-pinning, mfp

I am using mfp 8 and this is a hybrid application is in Angular 7 with cordova.

I have implemented for certificate pinning. But getting undefined. Tried to put in deviceready also. Also tried in defferent places but same error. Could any one help please.

I have placed the certificate file in android code 'assests/certificates/mycer.cer'.

```
ngOnInit() {
    WL.Client.pinTrustedCertificatePublicKey('mycer.cer').then(() => {
        console.log("success pinning")
    }, () => {
        console.log("failure pinning")
    });
}
```

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')

[image: Console Err message]

Comment: Try to access any other MFP APIs before calling pinTrustedCertificatePublicKey API. See if other MFP APIs are accessible. To me looks like MFP SDK is not initialised yet.

Comment: I have tried WL.Client.getEnvironment() which is working but only this pinTrustedCertificatePublicKey() is not working.